# Cannot resolve Places, Google play services

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have add the liberary of Google Play services as :

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

for using Google Places API, but still it does not resolve the 'Places' interface below:

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

For using Google Places API, which liberary I have to use or import as a seprate project. Also it does not resolve below too:

`import com.google.android.gms.nearby`

Comment: Have followed [https://developers.google.com/places/android/start]?

Comment: For initialize gPluse client follow https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_plusclient

Comment: Yes, I am following the same document, only to add google play service to the project and its respective dependencies. Not able to find the correct way to resolve the issue

Comment: @JaiSoni but that still does not resolve, I need to add the Places interface..!!

Comment: Resolved: I have the the jar file separately into the lib folder. Thanks :)

Comment: @Neha Then give answer of your question and mention jar u have included and accept it

Comment: I have added the google-play-services.jar to the lib folder; compile it in build.gradle file as : compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar') and that's it. My issue got resolved.

Comment: Please go to this link for correct answer:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968189/android-studio-can-not-resolve-com-google-android-gms-location-places-autocomple]

Answer (score 5):

Consider to add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:<latest version>` to the `build.gradile`.