# Android studio can not resolve com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am trying to implement a autocomplete places search following this article.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/

I have followed all steps, and also added proper dependencies in my build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Also here are the meta data section in my manifest.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

also I have all the required SDK components installed. Still my android studio can not resolve the **places** part in the following imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
```

this is how they look as they can not find the Places part.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? I am using SDK 19 for my app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Places API was only added in [Google Play services 7.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html): you'll need to update your dependency to be at least `7.0.0`, although the latest as of this answer is `15.0.0`.

Note in *almost every case*, you should use [selective APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) to only include the portions of Google Play services you need. In that case, you'd actually use a dependency such as

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
```

Comment: My issue is that given that it is adviced not to mix playservice versions, i still can't resolve the PlacesAutocomplete component with the latest version of the google play service (8.3.0). I need some assistance @ianhanniballake

Comment: @larrytech - I'd suggest looking through the [connecting to the Places API guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#connect-client) and the [autocomplete guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) and asking a separate question with your code and where you are running into an issue with adding auto-complete.

Comment: i am trying to use this code inorder to create an intent that will call the placeautomplete action, Intent interestintent =new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                        .build(this);                                                                                                 This doesn't work as the PlaceAutocomplete class fails to resolve. Like i said, am using the latest version of playservices version 8.3.0 and this code is gotten from the 'connecting to the places API guide'.

Comment: @larrytech I have same as this problem and my play-services:8.3.0 couldn't resolve com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete ,how can I solve it?

Comment: @SaeedHashemi - make sure to check out the [latest developer guide for Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) - things have changed.

Comment: @ianhanniballake what exactly  has changed?

Comment: @AnandSavjani - if you have a better answer, please do add it. For people using the less than 7.0.0 dependency, this is indeed the correct answer

Answer (score 49):

Add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:<version>`, where `<version>` is perhaps at least: `9.2.1` under `dependencies` in your modules's `build.gradle`

Comment: Thanks! This is a must for newer versions of Play Services, as Google Places API is not on the Location bundle anymore.

Comment: This should be newly accepted answer. Places API is not on Location anymore!

Comment: Yea, this helped me. The other answers didnt solve my problem.

Comment: ary behtreen dedia lrky

Answer (score 26):

**In play-services 9.2.0 the places API is no longer located in location. Those are now in their own places dependency. To resolve those you should add this to your build.gradle.**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

check out

[Places class is removed from android play services 9.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068786/places-class-is-removed-from-android-play-services-9-2-0/38075730#38075730)

Answer (score 8):

Since Play Services version 9.2 we should add the following dependancy to access Google Places API.

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
```

The latest version at the time of this writing.

The accepted answer for this thread was outdated.

Answer (score 7):

Add following two dependencies in your **build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

try including 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'`

Just add it in your **dependency** *(build.gradle [Module:Application])*
Then **file -> Invalidate caches/restart-> invalidate and Restart**

Answer (score 0):

For latest versions of google play services for location changes have been made. Check [[Selective Google Play Services API not finding classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077928/selective-google-play-services-api-not-finding-classes])

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with the same issue recently and adding this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.0'
```

to my dependency under `build.gradle`(app) file solves the problem for me.

NB: make sure the version of your dependencies are all thesame if not you will encounter or errors