# Trouble using the Google Places Api

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

Alright, so basically I've been experimenting with the Google Places Api and I've reached a bit of trouble.

So the documentation says `import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataApi`

So I've added `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87`
but when I try to do the `import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataApi` it does not give me an option to do `.places`, like in the `.location`  `.places` is not an option. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: You need at least Google Play Services 7.0.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968189/android-studio-can-not-resolve-com-google-android-gms-location-places-autocomple/30968303#30968303